# Regex on Keydown To restrict only numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function LettersOnly(e) {
    var charTyped = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var letterRegex = /[a-zA-Z._^%$#!~@,-\s\b`&]+/;
    if (!(charTyped.match(letterRegex)) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my code to restrict only numbers but here special characters are also not coming...it is on key down

Comment: Try this /^([^0-9]*)$/ Not numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restrict only numbers use:

```
letterRegex = /[^0-9]/;
```

See example:

```js
$("#text").keypress(
            
    function (e) {
    var charTyped = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var letterRegex = /[^0-9]/;
    
    if (charTyped.match(letterRegex)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="text">
```

Comment: @Tanmay added a example.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex pattern to match only "non-digit" characters:

```
...
var letterRegex = /\D+/;
```

Comment: @Tanmay, at least, you should try

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the regex for number after that return false if number matched else return true.

Example

```
function LettersOnly(e) {
    var charTyped = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var numberRegex = /\d+/;
    if (charTyped.match(numberRegex ) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: HERE also special characters are getting restricted

Comment: characters which are on number !@#$%^&*() these

Answer (score 0):

In keydown I guess we cannot restrict numbers barring !@#$%^&*() so I did in keypress and it works like a charm.Thanks everyone...